# AngularJS : Adding animation when div tag is updated

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am stuck in this problem where I have a div tag which updates and shows a list of images. I want to add animation when the value in the div tag is updated in the transition from one set of images to another.

[image]

Here as you can see in the bottom there are a set of images for girl's hair. And when the user goes to other tab, a different set of images comes. I want animation in that transition.

The AngularJS part for the transition is as follows :

```
<div ng-swipe-left="avDesignController.onSwipeLeftAction()" ng-swipe-right="avDesignController.onSwipeRightAction()">
    <!-- CUSTOMIZABLE TAB BAR -->
    <div class="tab-bar-container" >
        <div class="scrollmenutab">

            <!-- CUSTOMIZABLE MENU -->
            <div ng-repeat="customizable in customizables"
                 ng-click="avDesignController.onCustomizableClicked($event)"
                  style="display: inline;">
                    <a ng-if="customizable.allowed == 1">
                        <div ng-class="{selected: $index==currentIndex}">
                            <div ng-if="customizable.name == 'Hair'">
                                <img class="scrollmenutab-icon"
                                                    id="{{customizable.name}}-{{$index}}"
                                                    src="/app/app_resources/icons/{{genderImage}}Hair.png">
                            </div>
                            <div ng-if="customizable.name != 'Hair'">
                                        <img class="scrollmenutab-icon"
                                            id="{{customizable.name}}-{{$index}}"
                                            src="/app/app_resources/icons/{{customizable.name}}.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
            </div> <!-- MENU : END -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- CUSTOMIZABLES -->
    <div class="avdesign-item-container" id="avdesign-item-container">
        <div id="four-columns" class="grid-container" >

            <!-- LOAD CUSTOMIZABLES IF NOT LAST ITEM IN TAB -->
            <ul ng-if="currentIndex < (customizables.length - 1)"
                class="rig columns-4">
                <li ng-repeat="customizableItem in currentCustomizable.customizable_item">
                    <img class="tab-icon"
                         src="/app/app_resources/resources/av/{{avatarInfo.name}}/as/{{customizableItem.as}}"
                         id="customizable-{{$index}}"
                         ng-click="avDesignController.onCustomizedItemClicked($event)"
                         ng-class="{highlight: customizableItem.id==currentID}">
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- LOAD OUTFITS (FROM avatarOutfit) IF LAST ITEM IN TAB -->
            <ul ng-if="currentIndex == (customizables.length - 1)"
                class="rig columns-outfit">
                <div ng-repeat="brand in outfitBrand" ng-style="{'margin-bottom':'1vh'}">
            <div class="brand-icon" >
                            <img src="/app/app_resources/icons/{{brand.bg_image}}">
            </div>
                <li ng-repeat="outfit in brand.outfitList">
                    <img class="outfit-icon"
                         src="/app/app_resources/resources/av/{{avatarInfo.name}}/as/{{outfit.as}}"
                         id="outfit-{{$index}}"
                         ng-click="avDesignController.onOutfitItemClicked($event,$parent.$index)"
                         ng-class="{highlightOutfit: $index==avatar.outfit_index && $parent.$index==indexParent}">
                </li>
            </div>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the functions being called in the JS part is updating accordingly the images.

**So Question being how to add transition animation for the same element when it is updated because we are never leaving or entering that element tag**

Comment: ng-animate will help OR you can add animation classes on the fly. https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @hunzaboy My question is not what animation to add. My question is how to add animation while transitioning (when div tag is updated).

Comment: Have you looked into ng-animate docs?

Comment: @hunzaboy Yeah, things like ngEnter, ngLeave etc are working fine when changing the element tag but not in the same tag element. Don't know which other thing to use.

Comment: can we see a working example?

Comment: Just see how the transition happen in WhatsApp when transitioning between tabs.

Answer (score 5):

Your question  is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220107/update-div-element-after-loading-image-using-angular-js)

Html

```
<div ng-controller="c">
<div id={{my_id}} width={{widthOfOutsideWrapper}} height={{heightOfOutsideWrapper}}>
       <img ng-src="{{src}}" imageonload />
</div>
</div>
```

and in controller
var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                alert('image is loaded');
                scope.widthOfOutsideWrapper= this.width;
                scope.heightOfOutsideWrapper= this.height;
                scope.my_id = "testing";
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('c', function($scope) {
    $scope.src ="https://www.google.com.ua/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
});
```

and http://jsfiddle.net/2CsfZ/855/ working example is available here

Comment: But I don't want when the image is loaded. My problem is that when the user is swiping and moving to the other tab, the transition should have the animation like a native app, so the transition from this set of image to the other set of image should have the animation.

Comment: so you want effect when user selects a different image .. I am guessing you will add some class when the user selects something you should have on click event for that ?  why not try that

Comment: Like on top of the image list you see the tabs, right, so when transitioning from one tab to another the list of images down changes. There the transition and animation happen.

Comment: so you have tab changing  event ?? why dont you add animation when new page or div is loaded on-load event ?

Comment: Not a new div is added, just that the Customizable div is updated with the respective images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328102/how-to-detect-content-change-event-on-a-div try this

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is very helpful and might be of a great help for many.

But the answer to my question is you simply can't. `ngAnimate`'s `ngEnter` and `ngLeave` will not able to recognize a change unless the element is changed and not what is inside the element.

So either some hack needs to be applied like using `ngRepeat` with different `id's` for different updation that happens to the element or something else needs to be done.